# How are the footnotes numbered?

Tags: footnotes

How are the footnotes normally numbered? In a document I have inserted only one footnote and its number is 5.

Is this normal? Is there a convention as to how should a footnote be numbered according to typographical (or other) rules? If not how do I fix it?

The document is based on [this](https://conferences.cwa.gr/aiai2016/submission/) template.

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{Author 1\inst{1}, Author 2\inst{2}, Author 3\inst{3}, Author 4\inst{4}, \and Author 5\inst{1} }

\institute{Institute 1
\and
Institute 2
\and
Institute 3
\and 
Institute 4}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\lipsum[1]

\end{abstract}

\keywords{Keyword 1, Keyword 2}

\section{Title}

Text\footnote{Explanation} here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, that's not 'normal', i.e. it should not start with `5`. Looks like  you (or a package) have screwed up the `footnote` counter.... Without your document it's hard to tell

Comment: At any given point in your document you can set `\thefootnote` and see the value of the `footnote` counter. Perhaps that'll give you an indication *where* something is going wrong. It may be that you (or some package) used the `footnote` counter for something other that footnotes.

Comment: @Adam: `\inst` command provides the footnote superscripts in your author list. Apparently, the footnote counter is not reset afterwards. This looks like a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of `\maketitle` command, the `footnote` counter is set to the value of `\fnnstart`, which in turn is set in `\institutename`.

However, the value is wrong at the time of `\maketitle`.

Here's a small patch that replaces `\fnnstart` with `0`.

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xpatchcmd}

\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{%
  \setcounter{footnote}{\fnnstart}%
}{%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
}{}{}




\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{Author 1\inst{1}, Author 2\inst{2}, Author 3\inst{3}, Author 4\inst{4}, \and Author 5\inst{1} }

\institute{Institute 1
\and
Institute 2
\and
Institute 3
\and 
Institute 4}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\lipsum[1]

\end{abstract}

\keywords{Keyword 1, Keyword 2}

\section{Title}

Text\footnote{Explanation} here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably hacking `\maketitle` is better.

Comment: @egreg: I am just looking into the code

Comment: @egreg: Yes, right at the start, but at the end it's `\setcounter{footnote}{\fnnstart}%`

Comment: It seems to be a precise choice of the class: if there's only one institution, it is not numbered. Otherwise the footnotes go on from the last institution number.

Comment: @egreg: I found that too, in the meantime. I provided the patch anyway. If this is 'class' evil doing, it will be rejected anyway. I find this 'design' weird, however

Comment: `\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\fnnstart}{0}{}{}` should work